# Wait for InjectUser in Angular 2/Meteor

Tags: angular2-meteor

I've got a simple component set up as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';   
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'; 
import { InjectUser } from 'angular2-meteor-accounts-ui';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: 'Hello, World!'
})
@InjectUser('user')
export class myComponent implements OnInit {
    user: Meteor.User;

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.user); // undefined
    }
}
```

I expect the `this.user` to contain the logged in user's information.  On all subsequent components loaded it works but for the very first component that's loaded `this.user` is `undefined`

I would like for the user data to be pre-populated before any component is initialized.  That way I don't have to have the same subscription code on every component.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think `@InjectUser('user')` and `this.user` is used mostly for html rendering.In typescript code you should use `Meteor.user()` and `Meteor.userId()` either by assigning it to a variable or directly. everything you get from this.user you will also get from Meteor.user()

Comment: Thanks, using Meteor.userId() did the job, that seems to be correct on component init. I suppose for anything aside from rendering just the user ID should be enough (for subscriptions, etc).